# Image dimension column in Finder?

Tags: macos, finder

Is it possible to add a column in the list View in Finder, that displays the dimensions of image files ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just add the word Pictures (capital P) to the front of your folder name, and you will miraculously get Dimensions and Resolution as a column option.  Then just rename it back.

*Note: You may need to **right-click on the list view's header bar** to see this option, rather than View > Show View Options (`⌘` `J`).*

Comment: This is perfect because: 1/ This column becomes available in every subdirectories of the root directory.  2/ Clicking the header sorts the file according to the product of width*height. How did you find this ?

Comment: My mind. It is blown.

Comment: This is a very interesting solution, seems like a horrible workaround, but a workaround nonetheless. Great answer, Ivan.

Comment: That is awesome. Except for the way in which it is completely dumb. How would they possibly expect end users to know that? Short of using AskDifferent, of course.

Comment: I've tried this workaround, and I still just see two dashes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the answer is no, not directly.

Options for columns include:

- Date modified
- Date created
- Date Last Opened
- Date Added
- Size (file size, not image size)
- Version
- Kind
- Comments
- Label

and image size is not one of the choices.

[image]

You could, however, use a Folder Action to assign image size to the Comments field of a file in a folder and display the Comments column.

Note that in icon view, you can press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> and check "show item info" to display image sizes.