# Finder-List View_Resolution and Dimensions columns?

Tags: macos, finder, ventura

I'm running MacOS Ventura (13.5.2 which is current as of asking). When I'm viewing my files in a finder window, I would normally (in previous OS versions) have the ability to add "Resolution and Dimensions" columns. In Ventura, it seems the option to see these columns is missing. If I "Get Info" on an individual file, I can see that information, but I need to display it as a column within the finder to sort it.

Can I add metadata related columns to finder to show image file related content like dimensions or resolution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Image dimension column in Finder?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/68519/image-dimension-column-in-finder) It works for me on Ventura

Comment: @bmike  Absolutely worked! Headshaking solution, but worked. THANKS! 

BTW... I did search for the answer but for whatever reason didn't come across this one.

Comment: It’s all good. We love different wording pointing to one thread with the answer. I can’t believe it works, but here we are. Hidden functionality that’s very hard to discover and likely undocumented except for here. Closed questions are very useful for this place.